# Две виртуальные папки в одном сайте ASP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, asp

Помогите решить проблему. Имеется веб сайт на ASP. внутри 2 виртуальные папки "Пациент" и "Сотрудник" (по сути 2 разных сайта). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В каждой папке свой файл web.config, ссылающийся на форму аутентификации (соответсвенно для 2х разных сайтов - разные формы).

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="FwLoginCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="1200">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true" />
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" theme="Default" />
</system.web>
```

пытаюсь построить проект, студия выдает ошибку:

> Эта ошибка использования раздела, зарегистрированного как allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' вне уровня приложения. 
>   Эта ошибка может быть вызвана тем, что виртуальный каталог не настроен в IIS как приложение.

Игнорирую ошибку, выливаю руками (не студией) сайт на хостинг (masterhost.ru) - та же ошибка. 
Сайт написан не мной, поставили задачу, чтобы работало в интернете)) Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему? Как перестроить проект, чтобы проблемы не возникало?
Необходимо, чтобы эти два сайта открывались таким образом на одном домене:

- имясайта.ru/Пациент/
- имясайта.ru/Сотрудник/

формы аутентификации обязательно должно быть 2 разные. Заранее благодарна)

Comment: поместить их в тот же пул приложений, что и основной сайт не пробовали?

Comment: @Dmitry
к сожалению, я не знаю, как это делается.. Не подскажете? Это где-то на хостинге?

Comment: Ирина, если в IIS сайты уже как приложения, то вам надо в оснастке IIS нажать на дополнительные параметры и проверить какой пул приложения указан и сравнить с тем что указано в основном сайте, на счет мастерхоста не уверен, надо смотреть как у них с пулом

Comment: @Dmitry, да при чем тут вообще пулы?

Comment: @Dmitry "оснастке IIS нажать на дополнительные параметры" - я понимаю как это сделать на собственном локальном хостинге через настройки. Но проблема то как это сделать на виртуальном хостинге, где у меня доступ только к фтп, базам данных и личному кабинету)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, как вы правильно заметили в своем коментарии про уровень приложения, так вот виртуальный каталог вполне себе может быть приложением

Comment: @Dmitry может. Но не является - иначе бы не было ошибки.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тогда не понятен ваш вопрос про "да при чем тут вообще пулы?"

Comment: @Dmitry пулы приложений не влияют на иерархию настроек.

Comment: @PavelMayorov зато они влияют на наличие приложения как такового

Comment: @Dmitry нет, не влияют. Можно сделать два приложения в одном пуле. Или пул без приложений.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можно, но хостить приложение без пула это приводит к ошибкам

Comment: @Dmitry хостить приложение без пула невозможно. А если пул есть - то конкретно для этого вопроса совершенно не важно какой он

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент `authentication` можно использовать только в файле конфигурации уровня приложения, его нельзя использовать по виртуальному пути.

Если это - по сути два разных сайта - то зачем вы вообще сложили их в один проект? Сделайте два отдельных проекта, и развертывайте их по требуемым адресам.

---

Чтобы было понятнее, о чем речь. Ниже я привожу настройки своего локального IIS в виде картинки. Там `goodsMark-stats` - это обычная папка. `trash` - это виртуальный каталог. А `Sc.Web` - это веб-приложение.

Так вот, чтобы элемент `authentication` работал - надо, чтобы "Пациент" и "Сотрудник" были именно веб-приложениями. Этого нельзя добиться особым способом укладки файлов - это можно сделать только настройкой IIS.

[image: Пример настроек IIS]

---

PS вот самый простой способ создать веб-приложение, если все файлы уже на месте:

[image: Преобразование в веб-приложение]

Comment: Дада, вы все правильно говорите. Я уже все форумы излазила, и в принципе суть поняла, что эти два конфига конфликтуют. Уже пробовала выложить как 2 разных проекта, та же ошибка. На хостинге есть директория собственно сайта, внутри папка www, внутри нее 2 папки Пациент и Сотрудник. При публикации проектов в отдельности просто указываю разные папки. Но ошибка никуда не делась

Comment: @Irina Ugryumova дело не в папках, которые в файловой системе - а в настройках IIS.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Все получилось. Дело было действительно в том, что надо было преобразовать  в приложения)

Comment: И еще в личном кабинете на мастерхосте поставила режим Application Pool: Integrated. Было классик. Возможно это тоже сыграло роль

Comment: @IrinaUgryumova, нет, режим пула тут ни при чем. Но ваше изменение в любом случае не помешает :)
PS если ответ помог - отметьте его, пожалуйста, такой зеленой галочкой...

Comment: Готово) Еще раз спасибо!